# Initializing Array size to the size that is initialized in constructor throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, oop, scope, class-constructors

I'm trying to create a Shelter Class, where i can shelter Animals(which is another class that has two extensions Catg,Dog) but when i initalize the shelter's size with a constructor and then initialize an array after it, it throws an exception as i mentioned. Here's the code:

**Class Shelter**

```
public class Shelter {
    String name;
    int size;

    Shelter(String name,int size){
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
    }
    Animal[] A = new Animal[size];
    int i = 0;
    void addAnimal(Animal animal){
        if(i < size){
            A[i] = animal;
            i++;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The shelter is full.");
        }
    }
    void showAnimals(){
        for (Animal animal : A) {
            if(animal == null){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(animal);
        }
    }
}
```

**Class Animals**

```
public class Animal {
    String name;
    String gender;
    String colour;
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
    void interact(Animal anim){
        System.out.println(name + " is playing with " + anim.name);
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shelter shelter = new Shelter("Cemali",10);
        Dog dog = new Dog("Rex","Male","Brown");
        Catg catg = new Catg("Ash","Female","White");
        shelter.addAnimal(dog);
        shelter.addAnimal(catg);
        shelter.showAnimals();
    }
}
```

When i initialized the array without setting its size, and set its size in constructor, it worked without a problem. Why is that and how can i make it work with initializing its size outside of constructor? Here is how it looks like:

```
Animal[] A;
    Shelter(String name,int size){
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        A = new Animal[size];
    }
```

Comment: Just because `Animal[] A = new Animal[size]` is visually below your constructor _in your code_ does not mean it is called afterwards. The initializing code of your class variables is executed before your constructor code is executed. So `size` is still `0` when `Animal[] A = new Animal[size]` is executed. Hence the error. "_..how can i make it work with initializing its size outside of constructor_" - why would you want to do that, before knowing the actual size? You did it correctly in the last snippet.

Comment: On another matter, [don't use initial caps for variable names](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions) `animals` would be a much better name for your array